# Missing openGL texture flag GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I queried my opengl version using `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and it returned 3.3.0. As far as I know, 3.3 does have the GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE flag. However I'm unable to find it in my gl.h header nor does my compiler(VC++) recognize the flag. All my other openGL calls seem to run fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not ship with up-to-date OpenGL support. Check out [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for a solution to this problem.

Comment: So when my openGL says 3.3.0, is it not actually 3.3.0 then?

Comment: Your graphics card supports OGL 3.3.0. The `gl.h` header provided by Microsoft, not so much. The GLEW headers will provide all modern OGL functions, flags, etc.

Comment: GLEW is not necessary; there are a [number of alternatives to GLEW that exist](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: Certainly not, but I've found it to be a fairly straightforward option in the past.

Comment: To be clear about this: This is not an issue with Visual Studio but the OpenGL Application Binary Interface (ABI) specified for Windows. The Windows OpenGL API only goes up OpenGL-1.1 and everything beyond must be done through the extension mechanism. The Linux OpenGL ABI (there's no general GLX OpenGL ABI, it's been written down for Linux only) goes up to OpenGL-1.2. However a new Linux OpenGL ABI is in the making.